# Outlook 2012 signature with image without attachment

Tags: outlook, signature

I am trying to create an email signature in outlook 2010 with the company logo embedded.

As i am working my way trough this, i find it very strange that the included image is sent as an attachment.

It doesn't show as attachment on Outlook from other users. But it does on Mac, hotmail and so on..

I have already tried to include it via HTML, thus placing the image on a FTP and loading it from there, and i have tried including it trough the signature editor, both won't make it work..
Is there a code to make this function?

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/342554/how-to-embed-image-in-outlook-signature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be more a matter of how the client displays it.  Different clients are going to deal with the image in different ways, especially from a security standpoint.  Have you tried linking to an image directly from the Web?

Here's some additional info:

http://www.howto-outlook.com/faq/imagesignature.htm

Comment: Yes i have.. The image i am trying to use is coming straight of the website. I think it is indeed the way clients deal with the image. Hotmail does recognise it as an attachment in the overvieuw of all messages. but as soon as you open the message, there is no place to download the attachment. Because the attachment has already been downloaded.

Answer (score 5):

Why do you find it strange that the image is included as an attachment? Without it, there is no way for the recipient to view the image, as the email itself is text only. I imagine the only reason it doesn't show as an attachment in outlook is because outlook is smart enough to know that it's not a "real attachment" per se, but just the signature. Even then, I remember recieving signature images as attachments in older versions of outlook.

That said, it should be possible to use a linked image in your signature. [This link](http://www.msoutlook.info/question/538) explains how to do it.

> Creating an Outlook signature with an image or picture located on the Internet requires changing Outlook’s behavior on how to deal with linked images and also adding the image in a specific way. Once the image is inserted, you can use the Signature Editor to turn the image into a hyperlink to a website.
>
> **Set Outlook to link to pictures instead of embedding them**
>
> The first step is to change Outlook’s behavior on how to deal with linked pictures. By default Outlook will embed them with the message, but this would mean that your picture would be a reflection of when you created the message instead of when the the recipient is reading (or even re-reading) your message.
>
> Depending on how often you change your picture, this might be a non-issue but it would also mean that the picture gets added each time and thus making each message quite a bit larger. In several cases this could also result in your picture being added as an attachment and/or show the message with a paperclip icon. 
>   These are all things that you should want to avoid; if not for you, then definitely for the recipient’s sake.
>
> In Outlook 2003 and previous you can change this behavior via; 
>   Tools-> Options…-> tab Mail Format-> button Internet Format-> option: When an HTML message contains pictures located on the Internet , send a copy of the pictures instead of the reference to their location.
>
> In Outlook 2007 and 2010, this can behavior can only be changed via the Registry.
>
> Key: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\\Outlook\Options\Mail 
>   Value name; Send Pictures With Document 
>   Value: 0
>
> For more info about this registry key see; Where did "HTML options" go in Outlook 2007/2010?
>
> **Insert image as link**
>   When inserting the image into your signature, you must again make sure that the image is linked. If you do not do this, then the current image will be downloaded and saved within your signature and wouldn’t update when you change it on-line.
>
> **Outlook 2003**
>   Right click in the Signature Editor (do not use Advanced Edit) and choose; Insert Image…
>   Type the Internet address (URL) to the image in full when prompted for the Picture Source.
>   Click OK
>
> **Outlook 2007 and Outlook 2010**
>   Click on the Picture icon in the Signature Editor 
>   As the file name, type the Internet address (URL) to the image in full.
>   Instead of clicking on Insert, click on the little down arrow on the Insert button and choose; Link to File
>
> **Create a hyperlink**
>
> Once the image has been added, you can make it clickable and point it to a website via the the Hyperlink function.
>
> **Outlook 2003**
>
> Right click on the inserted image and choose; Edit Hyperlink
>   Outlook 2007 and Outlook 2010 
>   Select the image and click on the Hyperlink icon